# Sencha tags needs to be touched

Tags: discussion, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

There are 2500 questions with the [touch](/questions/tagged/touch) tag. 240 of them, are related to [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch), the rest to other touch related subjects.

So my conclusion is the [touch](/questions/tagged/touch) tag is probably too ambigious. And needs some cleanup.

My question on the subject is if the community agrees on a retag and what to do with [touch](/questions/tagged/touch)?

Comment: It needs touching up